# Why does solve in R give weird inverse?

Tags: r, matrix, inverse, matrix-inverse

M matrix

```
     1000          793504755
793504755    629649829362825
```

This is my matrix M in R
`solve(M)` gives this error :

```
solve(M)
Error in solve.default(M) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 8.36282e-20
```

while MMINV in excel gives the desired output for this 2 x 2 matrix

Is R computing inverse using some decomposition algorithm? Why is it not giving output for my matrix? The matrix determinant is also not zero. in fact it is a large value.

Comment: Please provide the Excel result. I don't believe it is correct within reasonable numeric error. Why are you calculating the inverse of this matrix? Maybe you could avoid this step?

Comment: @Roland, this is indeed weird. You could inverse it yourself and get the result by doing something like `M <- matrix(c(1000, 793504755, 793504755, 629649829362825), 2, 2); M2 <- matrix(c(629649829362825, -793504755, -793504755, 1000), 2, 2);(1/(M[1,1]*M[2,2] - M[1,2]*M[1,2]))*M2` Which does provide the desired result

Comment: you can get **an** answer via `solve(m,tol=1e-40)`, but I wouldn't trust it!

Comment: @BenBolker, why not? It gives the correct result as if you would calculate it by hand

Comment: @DavidArenburg Floating point accuracy is an issue here.

Answer (score 4):

You are having trouble because your matrix is *ill-conditioned*. You can solve it using the `Matrix` package without having to worry about intermediate steps:

```
library(Matrix)
solve(Matrix(M))
2 x 2 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
              [,1]          [,2]
[1,]  1.899097e+04 -2.393303e-02
[2,] -2.393303e-02  3.016117e-08
```

But there is some numerical imprecision in the result:

```
M %*% solve(Matrix(M))
2 x 2 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
            [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1.000000004    0
[2,] 0.001953125    1
```

This is because of the reciprocal condition number is smaller than the numerical precision afforded by doubles.

```
rcond(M)
[1] 8.362817e-20
storage.mode(M)
[1] "double"
.Machine$double.eps
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

However, the package `gmp` offers exact precision using rational numbers to give you the result you want:

```
library(gmp)
solve(as.bigz(M))
Big Rational ('bigq') 2 x 2 matrix:
     [,1]                  [,2]              
[1,] 932814562019/49118837 -5877813/245594185
[2,] -5877813/245594185    40/1326208599     
M %*% solve(matrix(as.bigz(c(M)),2))
Big Rational ('bigq') 2 x 2 matrix:
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    0   
[2,] 0    1
```

Answer (score 3):

This suffers from numerical difficulties. You can either use the "manual" method suggested by David or use the Choleski decomposition to get a somewhat reasonable estimate:

```
chol2inv(chol(M))
#              [,1]          [,2]
#[1,]  1.899097e+04 -2.393303e-02
#[2,] -2.393303e-02  3.016117e-08

chol2inv(chol(M)) %*% M
#             [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] 1.000000e+00 0.001953125
#[2,] 3.552714e-15 1.000000000
```

However, I'd suggest to avoid calculating the inverse of this matrix.